# align in array causes right shift

Tags: align, arrays

Compile the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}

\begin{document}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\[
  \setlength\arraycolsep{15pt} % default is '5pt'
  \begin{array}{@{} *{3}{L} @{}}
    \toprule
    \sin (x + 2k\pi) = \sin x                      &
    \cos (x + 2k\pi) = \cos x                      &
    \tan (x + 2k\pi) = \tan x                               \\ \midrule
    % \sin (x + \pi) = -\sin x                       &
    % \sin (x + \pi) = -\sin x                       &
    % \tan (x + \pi) = \tan x                                 \\ \addlinespace
    % \sin (\pi - x) = \sin x                        &
    % \cos (\pi - x) = -\cos x                       &
    % \tan (\pi - x) = -\tan x                                \\ \midrule
    % \sin (x + \frac{\pi}{2}) = \cos x              &
    % \cos (x + \frac{\pi}{2}) = -\sin x             &
    % \tan (x + \frac{\pi}{2}) = -\cot x                      \\ \addlinespace
    % \sin (\frac{\pi}{2} - x) = \cos x              &
    % \cos (\frac{\pi}{2} - x) = \sin x              &
    % \tan (\frac{\pi}{2} - x) = \cot x                       \\ \midrule
    \begin{aligned}[t]
       & \sin (\alpha+\beta)                         \\
       & = \sin\alpha\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\sin\beta
    \end{aligned}                      &
    \begin{aligned}[t]
       & \cos (\alpha+\beta)                         \\
       & = \sin\alpha\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\sin\beta
    \end{aligned}                      &
    \begin{aligned}[t]
       & \tan (\alpha+\beta)\\
       & = \frac{\tan\alpha + \tan\beta}
       {1 - \tan\alpha\tan\beta}
    \end{aligned}                               \\ \addlinespace[2ex]
    \sin 2x = 2 \cos x \sin x                      &
    \begin{aligned}[t]
      \cos 2x & = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x \\
              & = 2\cos^2 x - 1       \\
              & = 1 - 2\sin^2 x
    \end{aligned}                      &
    \tan 2x = \frac{2\tan x}{1 - \tan^2 x}                  \\ \addlinespace[2ex]
    \sin \frac{x}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos x}{2}} &
    \cos \frac{x}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos x}{2}} &
    \tan \frac{x}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos x}{1 + \cos x}} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{array}
\]
```

[image]

Pay attention to the second row regarding `sin(α+β)`. There's some weird right shift of the whole row. I notice that this happens when I use `aligned` in all three cells, but not happening when I only use `aligned` in one of the three cells (just like the next row). How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

There are two different spacing issues.

For technical reasons, after `&` the environments `align`, `aligned` and similar insert `{}` which has the effect of triggering `\mathop` or `\mathrel` spacing if the following item is an operator or a relation.

You need to kill these spacings.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}

\begin{document}

\[
  \setlength\arraycolsep{15pt} % default is '5pt'
  \begin{array}{@{} *{3}{L} @{}}
    \toprule
    \sin (x + 2k\pi) = \sin x                      &
    \cos (x + 2k\pi) = \cos x                      &
    \tan (x + k\pi) = \tan x                               \\ \midrule
    % \sin (x + \pi) = -\sin x                       &
    % \sin (x + \pi) = -\sin x                       &
    % \tan (x + \pi) = \tan x                                 \\ \addlinespace
    % \sin (\pi - x) = \sin x                        &
    % \cos (\pi - x) = -\cos x                       &
    % \tan (\pi - x) = -\tan x                                \\ \midrule
    % \sin (x + \frac{\pi}{2}) = \cos x              &
    % \cos (x + \frac{\pi}{2}) = -\sin x             &
    % \tan (x + \frac{\pi}{2}) = -\cot x                      \\ \addlinespace
    % \sin (\frac{\pi}{2} - x) = \cos x              &
    % \cos (\frac{\pi}{2} - x) = \sin x              &
    % \tan (\frac{\pi}{2} - x) = \cot x                       \\ \midrule
    \begin{aligned}[t]
       & \negthinspace \sin (\alpha+\beta)                         \\
       & \negthickspace = \sin\alpha\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\sin\beta
    \end{aligned}                      &
    \begin{aligned}[t]
       & \negthinspace \cos (\alpha+\beta)                         \\
       & \negthickspace = \sin\alpha\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\sin\beta
    \end{aligned}                      &
    \begin{aligned}[t]
       & \negthinspace \tan (\alpha+\beta)\\
       & \negthickspace = \frac{\tan\alpha + \tan\beta}{1 - \tan\alpha\tan\beta}
    \end{aligned}                               \\ \addlinespace[2ex]
    \sin 2x = 2 \cos x \sin x                      &
    \begin{aligned}[t]
      \!\cos 2x & = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x \\
              & = 2\cos^2 x - 1       \\
              & = 1 - 2\sin^2 x
    \end{aligned}                      &
    \tan 2x = \frac{2\tan x}{1 - \tan^2 x}                  \\ \addlinespace[2ex]
    \left\lvert\sin \frac{x}{2}\right\rvert = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos x}{2}} &
    \left\lvert\cos \frac{x}{2}\right\rvert = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos x}{2}} &
    \left\lvert\tan \frac{x}{2}\right\rvert = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos x}{1 + \cos x}} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also fixed the formulas in the last line: please, don't teach that the square root can take two values. The (least) period of the tangent is pi.

Also, don't do `\everymath{\displaystyle}`. It's wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and warmth. Those were actually typos for I haven't checked this document, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

So that `&=` gives infix spacing the left aligned columns of ams alignments have `{}` inserted, this means that you get `{}\sin`  which causes the `\mathop` thin space to be added. If you just use `\sin` at the top level then TeX automatically drops the extra space.

So you can either use `{}\sin` in the top level cases to force the space, or use `&\!\sin` in the `aligned` cases to remove the space, so things are consistent.